# Overflow Hidden is not working - CSS - Styled Components

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

For reasons I cannot identify overflow: hidden has decided not to work for my react application, at first yesterday or day before it worked and then for reasons I do not know it was not working and the X axis scroll was appearing. Then I came back next day to work on it and overflow: hidden was working as there was no x-axis scroll.

Today I have been working on the project fine, and then I restarted my laptop because npm was not installing part of material-ui's npm installations, it just paused halfway through. After restarting my laptop I tried to install again and worked fine, however now the overflow: hidden does not work as the scrolls on each axis have appeared.

I am very confused because my npm has been playing up and I have no idea why this would affect my css-styled components as their have been no code changes. Earlier on when I ran npm start it threw an error that I had not seen before so I ran npm update, and then npm start worked. I also constantly get those red warnings of a certain number of issues that need auditing whenever I install anything through npm now which I never use to get.

Sandbox Link Here

- I am developing it mobile first (Iphone 8/8plus size) so toggle the responsive view otherwise will look odd and might not make sense (haven't done media queries yet)
- For context when it was working fine the Y-axis scroll was on because the site is scrollable vertically just should not be scrolling horizontally
- I put overflow: hidden on all the containers now to try and get rid of horizontal scroll but no change

Because codepen does not work here are the main code files:

App.js

```
import React from 'react';

import Styled from 'styled-components';
import website from '../src/Assets/website (1).svg';
import development from '../src/Assets/development.svg';
import design from '../src/Assets/maintenance.svg';
import develop from '../src/Assets/code.svg';
import deploy from '../src/Assets/upload.svg';

import { Hero } from './Components/Hero';
import { Hero1 } from './Components/Hero1';
import { Hero2 } from './Components/Hero2';
import { Hero3 } from './Components/Hero3';

import NavAppBar  from './Components/Navigation'

import '@fontsource/roboto';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
        <NavAppBar/>
    
        <Hero/>
        <Hero1/>
        <Hero2/>
        <Hero3/>
    
    </div>

  );
}

export default App;
```

Hero.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Styled from 'styled-components';
import development from '../Assets/development.svg';
import design from '../Assets/maintenance.svg';
import develop from '../Assets/code.svg';
import deploy from '../Assets/upload.svg';

export const Hero = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Container>
                <Title>
                    Translating Business ideas to an professional online presence
                </Title>
                <WebsiteSvg/>
                <Subtitle>
                    The Full Front-End Package
                </Subtitle>
                <Design>
                    Design
                </Design>
                <DesignSvg/>
                <Develop>
                    Develop
                </Develop>
                <DevelopSvg/>
                <Deploy>
                    Deploy
                </Deploy>
                <DeploySvg/>
            </Container>  
        </div>
    )
}




const Container = Styled.div`
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    overflow: hidden;

    /* height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden; */
    /* background-color: #DBE6FD;
    background-color: #DEEEEA; */


`

const Title = Styled.div`
    position: absolute;
    width: 212px;
    height: 157px;
    left: 8%;
    top: 51px;

    font-family: Noto Sans;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 28px;
    display: flex;



    align-items: center;

    color: #000000;
    `

    const WebsiteSvg = Styled.div`
    position: absolute;
    width: 151px;
    height: 162px;
    left: 55%;
    top: 14%;

    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url(${development});
    transform: rotate(38.43deg);
`

const Subtitle = Styled.div`
    position: absolute;
    width: 171px;
    height: 35px;
    left: 10%;
    top: 189px;

    font-family: Noto Sans;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 28px;
    /* or 233% */

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;

    color: #000000;
`

const Design = Styled.div`
    position: relative;
    width: 64px;
    height: 37px;
    /* left: 40%; */
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    top: 45%;

    font-family: Noto Sans;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 28px;
    /* or 280% */

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;

    color: #000000;
`
const Develop = Styled.div`
    position: relative;
    width: 64px;
    height: 37px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    top: 55%;


    font-family: Noto Sans;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 28px;
    /* or 280% */

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;

    color: #000000;
`

const Deploy = Styled.div`
    position: relative;
    width: 64px;
    height: 38px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    top: 65%;

    font-family: Noto Sans;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 28px;
    /* or 280% */

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;

    color: #000000;
`
const DesignSvg = Styled.div`
 position: absolute;
  width: 95px;
  height: 95px;
  left: 4%;
  top: 53%;

  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url(${design});
  transform: rotate(38.43deg);
`
const DevelopSvg = Styled.div`
 position: absolute;
  width: 95px;
  height: 95px;
  left: 35%;
  top: 63%;

  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url(${develop});
  /* transform: rotate(-28.43deg); */
`
const DeploySvg = Styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  width: 95px;
  height: 95px;
  left: 67%;
  top: 74%;

  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url(${deploy});
  /* transform: rotate(-28.43deg); */
`
```

Hero1.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Styled from 'styled-components';
import webDesign from '../Assets/webDesign.svg';
import devices from '../Assets/devices.svg';
import profile from '../Assets/profile.svg';

export const Hero1 = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Container>
                <Title>
                    Services
                </Title>
                
                <ServicesBox>
                    <DesignSubtitle>
                        UI/UX Design
                    </DesignSubtitle>
                    <DesignSvg/>
                    <DesignText>
                        Experience designing with professional UI/UX principles utilising Figma
                    </DesignText>
                    <WebSubtitle>
                        Web Development
                    </WebSubtitle>
                    <DevicesSvg/>
                    <WebText>
                        Building Responsive and scalable websites and web apps with React
                    </WebText>
                    <MobileSubtitle>
                        Mobile Apps
                    </MobileSubtitle>
                    <ProfileSvg/>
                    <MobileText>
                        Building mobile webapps, lightning fast and no download required!
                    </MobileText>
                </ServicesBox>
            </Container>  
        </div>
    )
}




const Container = Styled.div`
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    overflow: hidden;
    justify-content: center;
    /* height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden; */
    /* background-color: #DBE6FD;
    background-color: #DEEEEA; */
    background-color: #DEEEEA;
`

const Title = Styled.div`
    position: relative;
    width: 253px;
    height: 45px;
    top: 8%;
    
    /* margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    vertical-align: middle; */
    

    font-family: Noto Sans;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 28px;

    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;

    color: #000000;
`
const ServicesBox = Styled.div`
    position: absolute;
    display: flex
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    top: 13%;
    height: 525px;
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    /* background-color: #DEEEEA; */
    border-radius: 70% 20% 60% 40%;
    /* opacity: 50%; */
`
const DesignSubtitle = Styled.div`
    position: relative;
    width: 108px;
    height: 36px;
    left: 37.5%;
    top: 5%;
    
    
  

    font-family: Noto Sans;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 28px;
    /* or 233% */


    align-items: center;

    color: #000000;
`
const WebSubtitle = Styled.div`
    position: absolute;
    width: 108px;
    height: 36px;
    left: 32.5%;
    top: 40%;

    font-family: Noto Sans;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 28px;
    /* or 233% */

    
    align-items: center;

    color: #000000;
`
const MobileSubtitle = Styled.div`
    position: absolute;
    width: 108px;
    height: 36px;
    left: 37.5%;
    top: 75%;

    font-family: Noto Sans;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 28px;
    

   
    align-items: center;

    color: #000000;
`
const DesignSvg = Styled.div`
    position: relative;
    width: 95px;
    height: 95px;
    left: 3%;
    top: 5%;

    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url(${webDesign});
`
const DevicesSvg = Styled.div`
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    right: 3%;
    top: 49%;

    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url(${devices});
`
const ProfileSvg = Styled.div`
    position: absolute;
    width: 95px;
    height: 95px;
    left: 5%;
    top: 85%;

    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url(${profile});
    transform: rotate(-12.43deg);
`
const DesignText = Styled.div`
    position: absolute;
    width: 185px;
    left: 38%;
    top: 18%;
    
    font-family: Noto Sans;
    font-style: bold;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 16px;
    /* or 140% */

    
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
`
const WebText = Styled.div`
    position: absolute;
    width: 175px;
    left: 1%;
    top: 55%;
    font-family: Noto Sans;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 16px;
    /* or 140% */

    
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
`
const MobileText = Styled.div`
    position: absolute;
    width: 165px;
    left: 41%;
    top: 90%;
    font-family: Noto Sans;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 16px;
    /* or 140% */

    
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
`
```

Hero2.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Styled from 'styled-components';
import diagram from '../Assets/diagram.svg'
import structure from '../Assets/structure.svg'
import js from '../Assets/js-format.svg'
import html from '../Assets/file.svg'
import css from '../Assets/css.svg'

export const Hero2 = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Container>
                <Title>
                    Web Development Skills
                </Title>
                <SkillsSvg/>
                <SkillBox>
                    <ReactSvg/>
                    <JsSvg/>
                    <HtmlSvg/>
                    <CssSvg/>

                </SkillBox>

            </Container>
        </div>
    )
}

const Container = Styled.div`
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    overflow: hidden;
    justify-content: center;
    /* height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden; */
    /* background-color: #DBE6FD;
    background-color: #DEEEEA; */
    background-color: #DBE6FD;
`
const SkillBox = Styled.div`
    position: absolute;
    display: flex
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    top: 35%;
    height: 400px;
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
    
  
`
const Title = Styled.div`
    position: absolute;
    width: 180px;
    height: 157px;
    right: 8%;
    top: 8%;

    font-family: Noto Sans;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 28px;
    /* or 140% */

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;

    color: #000000;
`
const SkillsSvg = Styled.div`
    position: absolute;
    width: 137px;
    height: 149px;
    left: 29px;
    top: 10%;

    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url(${diagram});
`
const ReactSvg = Styled.div`
    position: absolute;
    width: 75px;
    height: 79px;
    left: 45%;
    top: 5%;

    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url(${structure});

    transform: rotate(28.42deg);
`
    
const JsSvg = Styled.div`
    position: absolute;
    width: 75px;
    height: 79px;
    left: 70%;
    top: 30%;

    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url(${js});

    transform: rotate(28.42deg);
`
const HtmlSvg = Styled.div`
    position: absolute;
    width: 75px;
    height: 79px;
    left: 10%;
    top: 38%;

    transform: rotate(-25.03deg);

    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url(${html});
`
const CssSvg = Styled.div`
    position: absolute;
    width: 75px;
    height: 79px;
    left: 45%;
    top: 65%;

    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url(${css});

    transform: rotate(26.96deg);
`
```

Hero3.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Styled from 'styled-components';

export const Hero3 = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Container>
                <Title>
                    Portfolio
                </Title>
            </Container>
            
        </div>
    )
}

const Container = Styled.div`
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    overflow: hidden;
    justify-content: center;
    /* height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden; */
    /* background-color: #DBE6FD;
    background-color: #DEEEEA; */
    
`

const Title = Styled.div`
    position: absolute;
    width: 180px;
    height: 157px;
    right: 8%;
    top: 8%;

    font-family: Noto Sans;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 28px;
    /* or 140% */

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;

    color: #000000;
`
```

Comment: sandbox is displaying the default text. maybe  you havent updated/saved it?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-austin-lwnnd try this

Comment: still you are referencing `App` component which has teh default text. Hero* components are nowhere

Comment: Thats so annoying I hate codepen this has happened before but eveyrtime I click on link it works fine ill post the code files on here

Comment: https://lwnnd.csb.app/ try this link aswell but click bottom right button to open sandbox and it should take you to one i made - does for me - if I am doing something wrong please state in clear terms how to save it because it seems to be saved for me

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/live/gmveuuz

Comment: Here we go this should work

Comment: ok it is working. so the problem is the x-scrollbar?

Comment: Yeah I have no idea why it is there no was not there before and no code has changed

Comment: did you check my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a style property to parent div and it should work.

```
<div style={{ overflowX: "hidden" }}>
    <NavAppBar/>

    <Hero/>
    <Hero1/>
    <Hero2/>
    <Hero3/>

</div>
```

[example](https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-morning-ncnqq)

Comment: Apologies thought  I had replied, this does not work. Just tired it, and I and already tried this using styled components previously. This is confusing me so much because your solution is what I was using before pretty much whilst making this project and it randomly just stopped working which is why I came to stack overflow. And I can see in the codesandbox it works...

Comment: Wow okay for some reason now it works.... even when I take your style answer off the div and just use css I had previously overflow is now hidden. All i did was from phone screen size on google dev tools back to desktop size and then back to phone screen size and now it works... have no idea why toggling screen sizes two times through made it work will upvote your answer anyway as would be useful for other people to see

Comment: glad that even with this weird senario it worked and you can continue your work :D